# Want responsive sidebar in ionic 2

Tags: responsive-design, ionic2, application-design

I want a **responsive** sidebar menu in **ionic2**,
Which behave as website sidebar when it run in browser, 
and behave as sidemenu appeared with menu button when run as mobile application.

Can any one provide demo or solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 2 just released a [split pane component](http://blog.ionic.io/testing-split-pane-support/)

it is currently still in testing but you can install the nightly

```
npm install --save ionic-angular@2.0.1-201702161925
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SplitPane component available in Ionic 2.2.0 which is out on  March 8, 2017